# What is the proper way to add bundled files to the appcache manifest?

Tags: c#, razor, bundler, html5-appcache

I've created a prototype single-page web app that uses bundling for my javascript and css resources. I want to have more control over how the client's browser caches the resources, so I'm attempting to implement a cache manifest. **But I can't get the bundle urls in my manifest controller to match the bundle urls that are being used in my page.** (And that is causing my resources to not be handled properly)

Here is my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="/manifest/appcache">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viewContainer"></div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mustache")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my appcache manifest controller:

```
[NoCache]
public class ManifestController : Controller
{
    // GET: Manifest
    public ActionResult AppCache()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("CACHE MANIFEST");
        sb.AppendLine("");
        sb.AppendLine("# version " + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version);
        sb.AppendLine("");
        sb.AppendLine("CACHE:");
        sb.AppendLine(Styles.Url("/bundles/css").ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(Scripts.Url("/bundles/jquery").ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(Scripts.Url("/bundles/bootstrap").ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(Scripts.Url("/bundles/mustache").ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(Scripts.Url("/bundles/app").ToString());
        return Content(sb.ToString(), "text/cache-manifest");
    }
}
```

When rendered, my page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="/manifest/appcache">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="/bundles/css?v=05foeD1ouw8_HkR2BuZ1LeJIjvM0ZzqvfJQwDkNrBRE1" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viewContainer"></div>
    <script src="/bundles/jquery?v=rD9yxcIfC-_zwpaJ_9UPbUY1Niam5dFE8OFiugxkBeM1"></script>
    <script src="/bundles/bootstrap?v=oTDoDDX3Lkc7trL2ZkC3RJsRItMEUUqdj_UlAAmiNno1"></script>
    <script src="/bundles/mustache?v=W_BIas2vDP9wDqc-bEsDBkx1wQ0fDqYjeZKFVNXbZe01"></script>
    <script src="/bundles/app?v=3Mv6xc52lUG5p86bUG4RvyJWAbSPxRjHfgUd3W4MMw81"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my rendered appcache manifest looks like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# version 0.0.0.16497

CACHE:
/bundles/css
/bundles/jquery
/bundles/bootstrap
/bundles/mustache
/bundles/app
```

As you can see, the resource urls in the manifest do not match the resource urls in the page because of the cache-busting query string (present in the page, but not in the manifest). And that is causing the resources to not be cached properly. So my question(s) is(are):

1. How can I get the resource urls in my manifest controller to have the same cache-busting query string as the resource urls in my page?
2. Since I am using a cache manifest file, do I even need those cache-busting query strings in my bundled resources? (And if not, how can I turn them off?)

Comment: the cache bursting query string is super awesome to solve the stupid browser cache problem whenever you change those script files